# How to configure in values.yaml remote_write from prometheus to mimir

Tags: azure, prometheus, monitoring, grafana-mimir

my current setting

remoteWrite:
- url: "https://mimir-gateway.mimir.svc.cluster.local:9095/api/v1/push"

results in : [https://mimir-gateway.mimir.svc.cluster.local:9095/api/v1/push\"](https://mimir-gateway.mimir.svc.cluster.local:9095/api/v1/push%5C%22): context deadline exceeded"

When i tried http i got: "Post "
[http://mimir-distributor.mimir.svc.cluster.local:9095/api/v1/push\"](http://mimir-distributor.mimir.svc.cluster.local:9095/api/v1/push%5C%22):
net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x00\x00\f\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00

Any help how to make it work will be really appreciated

First i tried connecting with mimir-distributor, got error indicating i should do it by https. After changing to https i got error context deadline exceeded after increasing resources i got error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"

Then i switched to mimir-gateway "https://mimir-gateway.mimir.svc.cluster.local:9095/api/v1/push" and again i got error context deadline exceeded

In both cases i was counting that i will be able to establish writing from prometheus to mimir and later send data from mimir to grafana that is on different aks cluster

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if that the Kubernetes services mimir-gateway.mimir.svc.cluster.local and mimir-distributor.mimir.svc.cluster.local are reachable from the Prometheus instance.

If you are using HTTPS, ensure that the SSL/TLS certificates on the server (mimir-gateway or mimir-distributor) are valid . If self-signed certificates are used, make sure Prometheus is configured to trust them.

Double-check the Prometheus configuration for the remote_write section. also make sure that the URL is correct,

Comment: "If you are using HTTPS, ensure that the SSL/TLS certificates on the server (mimir-gateway or mimir-distributor) are valid . If self-signed certificates are used, make sure Prometheus is configured to trust them." I think this is the part im having trouble with we do have cert-manager on cluster but i just cant configure it right on mimir side